# Heroku run binary version of web(golang)

Tags: heroku, go

I'm trying to use https://github.com/ryandotsmith/null-buildpack
and have compiled `web` process version(linux x64)
but when i'm `doing git push heroku master` process hangs on

`remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: Build stream timed out, reverting to polling...............`

Procfile:

`web: /app/bin/www`

Comment: The README shows that your Procfile should have `program: /bin/<name>` rather than `web: ...` - have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was caused by a heroku issue, resolved now
https://status.heroku.com/